# An integral solves by complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts

I try to compute
$$
I:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan^2x}{x^2}\text{d}x
$$
by complex analysis.
This is my attempt:
Consider
$$
f(z)=\frac{\arctan^2z}{z^2},\frac{\pi }{2}\ge\text{arg}(z)>-\frac{3\pi}{2}
$$
and the contour
$$\begin{aligned}
&\gamma_1:\{t|t:-\infty\rightarrow\infty,t\in\mathbb{R}\}\\
&\gamma_2:\{\infty e^{i\theta}|\theta:0\to\frac{\pi}{2}\}\\
&\gamma_3:\{it|t:\infty\to 1\}\\
&\gamma_4:\{it|t:0\to\infty\}\\
&\gamma_5:\{\infty e^{i\theta}|\theta:\frac{\pi}{2}\to\pi \}
\end{aligned}$$
Then
$$
I+\int_{i\infty}^{i}\frac{(\arctan t+\pi i/2)^2-(\arctan t-3\pi i/2)^2}{t^2}\text{d}t=0
$$
But obviously note that the equality isn't true.Where are my mistakes?Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend to integrate by part first (to get rid of branch points): $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan^2x}{x^2}dx$$=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\arctan (x)xdx\Big(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\Big)dx$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)-\ln(x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=$$2\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x+i)}{1+x^2}dx-$$2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$. The second integral is zero; to evaluate the first - close the contour in the upper half-plane by a big half-circle ($\ln(x+i)$ does not have branch points there), and take a real part.

Answer (score 1):

$$ I \stackrel{\text{parity}}{=}2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan^2(x)}{x^2}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto \tan\theta}{=}2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\theta^2\,d\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=} 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\theta\cot(\theta)\,d\theta\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}-4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(\sin\theta)\,d\theta$$
and the last integral should be familiar.